# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager in android

Tags: java, android, usagestatsmanager

Hi i am using UsageStatsManager api to show some usage list to user. But i am facing some issue. i am getting this error in many device, in some device it's working fine. i am still surfing about this issue. can you guys please help me to solve this.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager
    at com.yourapp.fragment.AppUsageStatisticsFragment.onViewCreated(AppUsageStatisticsFragment.java:64)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5463)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code i have used:**

```
    private UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager;

   //i am getting error at below line.
    mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService("usagestats"); //Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE
```

**Manifest:**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

Check my [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourapp.batterystatus).

Comment: have you added permission in meanifest

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade yes.check my question now!

Answer (score 2):

`UsageStatsManager`  Added in API level 21 this is not a part of your appcompact API. So that's why before **API level 21** you will get the `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: but its working fine in api level 20. i checked my app in samsung galaxy s4.

Comment: @Nirmal its from official doc it available from API level 21

Comment: any other alternative way to use usagestatsmanager under 5.0. cleanmaster app using this. but i dont know how to use this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`UsageStatsManager` was Added in API level 21 so you will get this `ClassNotFoundException` on preLollipop.

Also some samsung and other devices throws `ClassNotFoundException` on lollipop too as they haven't included that class, You can only safely use the class in `API 22`

Comment: my compile sdk version is 22 and my target sdk version is 23

Comment: any other alternative way to use usagestatsmanager under 5.0. cleanmaster app using this. but i dont know how to use this!!!!